# css How to prevent image from shifting on page resize

Tags: css

[image]

When zoomed in to about 80 or 90 percent, these two images under trending articles are nicely centered but once I start zooming out, the images(articles) start shifting to the left. I want the images to keep its center-left and center-right look, but am not sure on how to achieve this

//HTML

```
<div id = "Article" class = "Article">                    
   <h2> What next for Italy </h2>
    <img src = "News_Images/Italy_Dissapointed.jpg" alt = "Udine" width = "330" height = "180">
    <p><i>Matteo Buonastella</i>, November 15, 2017</p>
    <button  class="btn btn-info"  onclick = "Atalanta3()">Read More</button>
    <div id = "display3" class = "display">
        <div id = "choose3"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id = "Article2" class = "Article2">
   <h2> Are Atalanta fatigued? </h2>
    <img src = "News_Images/Test1.jpg" alt = "Udine" width = "330" height = "180">
    <p><i>Matteo Buonastella</i>, May 22, 2017</p>
    <button  class="btn btn-info"  onclick = "Atalanta2()">Read More</button>
    <div id = "display2" class = "display">
        <div id = "choose2"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

//CSS

```
#Article{
   display:inline-block;
   margin-bottom:5%;
   margin-left:20%;

}

#Article2{
   display:inline-block;
   margin-bottom:5%;
   margin-left:20%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox to make sure the spacing stays consistent.

In the parent element, I've set the display to flex and then added `justify-content: space-around;` this means to space the elements out by putting more space around them.

```css
.articles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fake-image {
  height: 130px;
  width: 250px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="articles">
  <div class="article">
    <h2> What next for Italy </h2>
    <div class="fake-image"></div>
    <p><i>Matteo Buonastella</i>, November 15, 2017</p>
    <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <h2> Are Atalanta fatigued? </h2>
    <div class="fake-image"></div>
    <p><i>Matteo Buonastella</i>, May 22, 2017</p>
    <button>Read More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this is helpful